# laravel 4 The filename fallback must only contain ASCII characters

Tags: php, apache, symfony, laravel-4

My file has UTF-8 (greek) characters and i am unable to download it. I am using laravel 4. Here is my code:

//download

```
Route::get('file/download', function()
{
$file = 'uploads/πτυχιακή.odt';
return Response::download($file);
});
```

I get the following error(invalidArgumentException) message :the filename fallback must only contain ASCII characters

Any ideas of how to fix that issue..?

Comment: I'd go with renaming the files... Having them like that can be a headache at some different levels.

Comment: Same question on the Laravel forums, no real solution though, besides renaming the files. http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=61493

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a bug in the Response::download function. Change it to:

```
// File: vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Response.php

public static function download($file, $name = null, array $headers = array(), $disposition = 'attachment')
{
    $response = new BinaryFileResponse($file, 200, $headers, true);

    if (is_null($name))
    {
        $name = basename($file);
    }

   return $response->setContentDisposition($disposition, $name, Str::ascii($name));
}
```

https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/4296

**Laravel 5**

In Laravel 5, you can extend the *\Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory* class and override the *download()* method. Then, in a *ServiceProvider*, register your custom *ResponseFactory* as the default one:

```
// We extends \Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory class, that implements Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory

$this->app->singleton('Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory', function ($app) {
    return new MyCustomResponseFactoryExtendedFromResponseFactory($app['Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory'], $app['redirect']);
});
```

Doing this, you can use the default methods (*Response::json()*, *respose()->view()*, etc) and your custom methods in the same way: *Response::download()*, _response()->download

Answer (score 2):

As it is stated in http://laravel.com/docs/responses#special-responses:

> Note: Symfony HttpFoundation, which manages file downloads, requires
>   the file being downloaded to have an ASCII file name.

If I understand this correctly, ideally the filename should be stored with an ascii filename during the upload process and then returned with:

```
return Response::download(<ascii_filename>);
```

This is fine if it is acceptable that the filename is not the same as when it was uploaded.

However, if the filename must not change then the download of the file should triggered with:

```
return Response::download(<ascii_filename>, <original_file_name>);
```

This means that it is necessary to keep track of the original filename after storing the file during the upload process. This can be achieved either by simplifying the filename and storing the original filename in a database or by storing the filename with a name encoded in such a way that it can be converted back to its original name.

Keeping track of the original filename in a database makes it possible to simplify the filenames so that they are very recognisable (e.g. 'hallå där.txt' -> 'halla dar.txt').

However, using a database is not always an option. There are different ways of converting UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1 strings to ASCII in a way that they can be converted back (e.g. [base64_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) / [base64_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php), [mb_convert_encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) and others), each with pros and cons (for example, depending on if you want to be able to store the file with a recognizable name).

Comment: this solution does not work , even by passing a utf-8 name as second parameter to `downlaod` method , returned file name will be change to something else

Comment: I used mb_convert_encoding to encode in ASCII the original filename. And it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use / in the filename. If your file name contains / first remove it.

```
$file_name = str_replace(array("/", "\\", ":", "*", "?", "«", "<", ">", "|"), "-", $data->title);
$tempVideo = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), $file_name);
copy($data->file, $tempVideo);            
return response()->download($tempVideo, $file_name);
```